# Launching segue from tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to launch segue from tab bar item. When user touches an item on the tab bar. I want to launch a segue.

To do this I writed this code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tabs: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        if item.tag == 3 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test123", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Actually it works well except a problem. This is launching segue but also switching the tab. I don't want this. It should just launch start segue shouldn't switch the tab.

How can I prevent this problem?

Comment: add item.enabled = false in your if statement

Comment: It disables the tab bar item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the minimal changes to get your code work

in your `viewDidLoad()` add

```
self.delegate = self
```

Then implement delegate method

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    let shouldSelectIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers?.indexOf(viewController)
    if shouldSelectIndex == 2
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("test123", sender: self)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

That should work.

However I think you have design issues.

1. Subclass as a delegate is strange. Better separate delegate.
2. Instead of tag/indecies use introspection or another delegation or something

Comment: I am getting compiler error: Value of type CameraController has no member 'delegate'

Comment: I mean viewDidLoad of class TabBarController, also I updated the code